# How to assess the number of unique items?

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms, computer-science

I have a stream processing system which has a cache.
cache max size is $\text{100K}$ and the TTL for entries is $30$ minutes. I want to come up with a metric that will help me *assessing* the total number of items that were pushed to the system.

Note: I want to do it without having a set that simply holds all the unique keys.

Here's what I thought:
I can listen to the event of entry eviction and have two counters:

1. eviction_full_capacity - it means that the entry was removed because another item was needed to be added and the cache was full
2. eviction_ttl - the entry was removed because of TTL expiry (after $30$ minutes)

I can also count or check the rate of the input to the system.

obviously if there are less than $\text{100}K$ items then the exact answer is the max size of the cache. What if the number of unique items is greater than the cache max size?

Given the above, how can I assess the total number of unique items that were processed by the system?

Comment: Not clear to me where the "unique" part comes into play. Elements in the cache are distinct? Why you don't just add the two counters with the number of elements in the cache? At which rate an element is pushed to the cache? For how much time you "observe"?

Comment: @nicola, yes, elements in the cache are distinct (have unique keys). The thing is that the number of total items might be more than $100\text{K}$ and that's what I'd like to prove

Comment: @nicola, currently I don't have the rate so we can consider it as a parameter. I think that most of the items would be seen in a timeframe of $24$ hours.

Comment: @sleekster, may I ask what algorithm you have implemented now?

Answer (score 1):

The keywords are "sliding window", "conunt-distinct" and "hyperloglog".

---

You are dealing with the count-distinct problem, also known as the cardinality estimation problem that is explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-distinct_problem).

[The hyperloglog algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) should be an excellent candidate solution to your situation. It is based on the observation that the cardinality of a multiset can be estimated by calculating the maximum number of leading zeros in the binary representation of each item in the multiset.

Easy-to-use libraries that implement the hyperloglog algorithm in popular programming languages are readily available.  You can pick one to try different parameters and flavors. To start, you can compute a HyperLogLog sketch each day.